# jQuery Append with HTML tags doesn't show in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

When I append strings with HTML tags in them, they appear in IE11 yet they don't appear in Chrome. The append works fine when I don't include the span tags but for some reason when included browsers like Chrome and Firefox don't show the content.

```
function p(words){
        $("#parser").scrollTop = $("#parser").scrollHeight;
        $("#parser").append("\n" + words);
    }
p("<span class = 'choice' id='openstore'>Test Line</span>");
```

Comment: check on console what error you are getting.after that check ur browser setting that allow javascript to run or not.

Comment: What is problem fiddle works properly here http://jsfiddle.net/GQLNy/

Comment: I'm not getting any errors

Comment: I checked http://jsfiddle.net/GQLNy/ this fiddle it works on chrome also properly

Comment: oftheseal.com/hs is the site I'm working on and for some odd reason no appended span elements are showing

Comment: i am telling you please check ur browser setting.

Comment: Because you are using a textarea, jquery is appending the actual html elements to the textarea element, and since that is invalid html it doesnt show up. Open your console and goto the elements tab and view your `#parser` textarea you will see the spans as child elements of the textarea.

Comment: So it would be better if I were to put the span elements in a div or something like that?

Comment: You would have to, as textarea's only are supposed to have text in them.